# im4java, mac run issue

Tags: java, osx-lion, imagemagick, im4java

Every time when I try to run im4java in my java app got this error:

```
org.im4java.core.CommandException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-6.7.7/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib
at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:219)
at Main.main(Main.java:55)
Caused by: org.im4java.core.CommandException: dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-6.7.7/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib
at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.finished(ImageCommand.java:253)
at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.run(ProcessStarter.java:314)
at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:215)
... 1 more
```

My system is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 (11E53) and ImageMagic is installed and working properly from command line, but not in Java.

Only thing what I changing is:

```
String myPath= "**************/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.7.7/bin";
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(myPath);
```

Thats why its finding convert, but not library. Don't know what to do...

Comment: never mind, I installed virtual box and switch to Linux.

Comment: im4java manual says that you can set the searchpath with a list of paths. Does adding the lib path to the list help?

Comment: I abandon Mac, but I'm forced to use Windows now, have any idea how to run im4java on Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem with a manually installed ImageMagick.

But it works with a ImageMagick installed by homebrew:
http://sethvargo.com/20110726/install-imagemagick-on-mountain-lion/

Answer (score -1):

Look where located the script "convert"
I have it in the folder /opt/local/bin/
Because I installed ImageMagick the command port